# heap_stat gives uncomplete results for dump of C# application

Tags: c#, debugging, dump, pykd

While running [heap_stat](https://github.com/goldshtn/windbg-extensions/blob/master/heap_stat.py) on a dump of a C# application, I end up with incomplete information, as you can see from the start of this summary:

```
Statistics:
Type name                  Count  Size     Allocated Size
combase!CClientChannel     20094  Unknown  69080323345238
combase!CStdIdentity       8657   Unknown  28467142107174
combase!CDestObject        4326   Unknown  14809067561232
clr!CAssemblyName          2831   Unknown  9689455665024
...
```

As you can see, the "Size" is always "Unknown", although the "Allocated Size" is filled in.

How can I alter the heap_stat script in order to get this information?

Comment: What is the application doing? Are you trying to troubleshoot a Shell extension? You can open a memory dump in Visual Studio instead of trying to use low-level debugging, but the questions you've asked in the last few days suggest you're trying to troubleshoot problems that may have nothing to do with .NET. `combase.dll` is used in COM APIs and isn't part of .NET. Neither is CListViewHost.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: indeed, I'm still working on the same problem: a .NET application, who uses every day ±100Mb more memory. That memory increase is believed to be outside of the .NET scope, hence the choice of native dump analysis (like using "heap_stat.py" script). But as that script has been written for analysing C++ dumps quite some things seem not to be working properly.